# Looping with variable in $_POST doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, forms, loops, post, snmp

I am writing a small script to do power controls on APC power bars. I have the script working perfectly, but I am extending it to a unit that has 24 outlets and I don't want to the script to have a power off, reboot and power on section for each port, so I decided to use a loop as follows:

```
 for ($Outlet = 1; $Outlet <= 24; $Outlet++) {
    //Power On
    if(isset($_POST['APCPowerOnA$Outlet'])) {
         $shell_command = "snmpset -v 1 -c $community $apc01_ip $mib.$Outlet i 1"; 
         $return=array();
         exec($shell_command, $return);
     }
    //Power Off
    if(isset($_POST['APCPowerOffA$Outlet'])) {
         $shell_command = "snmpset -v 1 -c $community $apc01_ip $mib.$Outlet i 2"; 
         $return=array();
         exec($shell_command, $return);
     }
    //Reboot
    if(isset($_POST['APCPowerRebootA$Outlet'])) {
         $shell_command = "snmpset -v 1 -c $community $apc01_ip $mib.$Outlet i 3"; 
         $return=array();
         exec($shell_command, $return);
     }
```

I include this file in another file which has the following code per port:

```
   <form method="post" action="[XXX]">
   <input type="submit" name="APCPowerOnA1" value="Power On" id="APCPowerOnA1" />
   <input type="submit" name="APCPowerOffA1" value="Power Off" id="APCPowerOffA1" />
   <input type="submit" name="APCPowerRebootA1" value="Reboot Port" id="APCPowerRebootA1" />
   </form>
```

Note action="[XXX]" is just a place holder for this forum, don't want to give the url on a public forum :)

With one of these per port, each time incrementing the ID and Name by 1 (this example being port 1).

When I run the script, replacing the variables: $Outlet with say 1 the port responds to commands, but when I try and loop it, nothing seems to work. When I do an echo for "APCPowerOnA$Outlet" I get APCPowerOn1, APCPowerOn2 ... APCPowerOn24, so why does POST not work? I am missing something obvious?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Change $_POST['APCPowerOffA$Outlet'] to $_POST["APCPowerOffA$Outlet"]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need double quotes in order for the variable to be interpolated within the string:

```
$_POST['APCPowerOnA$Outlet'] =>  $_POST["APCPowerOnA$Outlet"]
```

Or, you can use string concatenation:

```
$_POST['APCPowerOnA' . $Outlet]
```

If you don't do one of these, you're literally accessing the index `APCPowerOnA$Outlet`.

Comment: +1 for the answer which i was also going to POST! and For me second option of string concatenation is good!

Comment: +1 that did the trick! I did try that before but it didn't work, must have been tired eyes. Many thanks for the explanation, all working :)